# Qt + сторонняя библиотека. Как заставить работать сигналы и слоты?

Tags: qt

Помогите как правильно подключить Q_OBJECT чтобы работали сигналы и слоты.
пример:
**mycall.h**

```
#ifndef MYCALL_H
#define MYCALL_H
#include <pjsua2.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <pj/file_access.h>

#include <QDebug>

#include "myaccount.h"

#define THIS_FILE "main.cpp"

using namespace pj;

class MyAccount;

class MyCall : public Call
{

private:
    MyAccount *myAcc;

public:
    MyCall(Account &acc, int call_id = PJSUA_INVALID_ID);

    virtual void onCallState(OnCallStateParam &prm);
    virtual void onCallMediaState(OnCallMediaStateParam &prm);
};

#endif // MYCALL_H
```

**mycall.cpp**

```
#include "mycall.h"


MyCall::MyCall(Account &acc, int call_id)
    : Call(acc, call_id)
{
    myAcc = (MyAccount *)&acc;
}

void MyCall::onCallState(OnCallStateParam &prm)
{
    PJ_UNUSED_ARG(prm);

    CallInfo ci = getInfo();
    //std::cout << "*** Call: " <<  ci.remoteUri << " [" << ci.stateText << "]" << std::endl;

    if (ci.state == PJSIP_INV_STATE_DISCONNECTED)
    {
        myAcc->removeCall(this);
        /* Delete the call */
        delete this;
    }
}

void MyCall::onCallMediaState(OnCallMediaStateParam &prm)
{
    CallInfo ci = getInfo();

    // Iterate all the call medias
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < ci.media.size(); i++)
    {
        if (ci.media[i].type==PJMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO && getMedia(i))
        {
            AudioMedia *aud_med = (AudioMedia *)getMedia(i);

            // Connect the call audio media to sound device
            AudDevManager& mgr = Endpoint::instance().audDevManager();
            aud_med->startTransmit(mgr.getPlaybackDevMedia());
            mgr.getCaptureDevMedia().startTransmit(*aud_med);

        }
    }
}
```

при простом добавлении макроса в класс не помогает

Comment: Ваш класс должен начинаться так `class MyCall : public QObject, public Call
{
Q_OBJECT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы работали сигналы и слоты, ваш класс должен быть наследником `QObject` и иметь в private-области макрос `Q_OBJECT`

Comment: сделал так class MyCall :public QObject ,public Call { Q_OBJECT теперь на реализацию ругается. хотя я там тоже qobject подставлял ndefined reference to `vtable for MyCall' реализация: MyCall::MyCall(Account &acc, int call_id):QObject(),Call(acc, call_id)

Comment: @Alexey_Smirnov Сборка->Запустить qmake. Затем пересоберите проект. Должно помочь.

Comment: да. Спасибо) Двинулось с мертвой точки  ;)